# Strange behavior when incrementally sampling using RcppArmadillo::sample

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm trying to implement some draws using a polya urn scheme using Rcpp.  Basically, I have a matrix I'm drawing from,  and a 2nd matrix with weights proportional to the probabilities.  After each draw, I need to increase the weight of whichever cell I drew.

I was running into some indexing errors which lead me to examine the sampling more generally, and I found that my weight matrix was getting modified by RcppArmadillo::sample.  Two questions (1) is this behavior that I should have expected or is this a bug which I should report somewhere?  (2) Any ideas on current work-around?  Here's a reproducible example:

```
#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp ;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void sampler(int N, int inc, NumericMatrix& weight_matrix, int reps) {

  IntegerVector wm_tmp = seq_along(weight_matrix);
  Rcout << "Initial weight_matrix:\n" << weight_matrix << "\n";

  int x_ind;
  for(int i = 0; i < reps; ++i) {
    x_ind = RcppArmadillo::sample(wm_tmp, 1, true, weight_matrix)(0) - 1;
    Rcout << "Weight matrix after sample: (rep = " << i << ")\n" << weight_matrix << "\n";
    Rcout << "x_ind: " << x_ind  << "\n"; 
    // get indices
    weight_matrix[x_ind] = weight_matrix[x_ind] +  inc;
    Rcout << "Add increment of " << inc << " to weight_matrix:\n" << weight_matrix << "\n";
  }
}
// 
// // [[Rcpp::export]]
// IntegerVector seq_cpp(IntegerMatrix x) {
//   IntegerVector tmp = seq_along(x);
//   IntegerVector ret = RcppArmadillo::sample(tmp, 2, true);
//   return ret;
// }

/*** R
weight_matrix <- matrix(1, 5, 2)
sampler(5, 1, weight_matrix, 3)

weight_matrix <- matrix(1, 5, 2)
sampler(5, 0, weight_matrix, 3)
*/
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is known and documented behaviour.

You could do

i)  Use `Rcpp::clone()` to create a distinct copy of your `SEXP` (ie `NumericMatrix`).

ii) Use an Armadillo matrix instead and pass as `const arma::mat & m`.

There are architectural reasons having to do with the way R organizes its data structure which mean that we cannot give you *fast access* (no copies!) and also protect against writes.

Comment: Thank you (as always) for your responses and patience.  I understand i), and I was leaning that direction.  Do you know where I might learn more about ii)?  I was under the impression that things like `const` were part of the definition of a function, not a property I could pass into a function.